# How to send a custom HTTP header value that includes trailing whitespace

Tags: c#, .net, http, http-headers, whitespace

```
POST /api/auth? HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
My-Header-Value: 12345  // <= note that there's 2 trailing white spaces
cache-control: no-cache
```

As can see from above example, there's a custom header, `My-Header-Value`, used in the HTTP request, where the value contains some trailing spaces.

I notice that the trailing spaces automatically get ignored and received value is actually `12345` instead of 12345  . According to the spec, this is intended by design.

But what if I really need to include the white spaces in this case? Is there any way that I can do it?

Comment: Why not add something (say semicolon `;`) after the trailing whitespace?

Comment: @DannyChen tried it with Postman, but didn't seem to work either. Same with double quotes. Kinda weird :(

Comment: I tried `12345  ;` is working.

Comment: @DannyChen thanks for the suggestion, but I ended up with using based64 encoded approach which works fine for me as well.

Comment: Ya, base64 string is better in this case. You can post it as an answer, it's easier for someone else who has the same question to find the solution.

Comment: @DannyChen thanks for your comments. The answer has been added now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue I had, I created following helper method to base64 encode the value. The base64-encoded string complies with the standard as per [RFC 2047](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt).

```
private static string GetBase64EncodedHeaderValue(string value)
{
    var result = string.Format("=?UTF-8?B?{0}?=", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value)));
    return result;
}
```

Then I can do something like `request.Headers["My-Header-Value"] = GetBase64EncodedHeaderValue("12345  ")`. This way, the white spaces will be retained in the header value.

Comment: That will work, but any other encoding that avoids the trailing whitespace as well. Note that HTTP does not define any specific role for RFC 2047 encoding.